# Lock-free data structures in C++ = just use atomics and memory-ordering?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, atomic

I used to see the term "lock free data structure" and think "ooooo that must be really complex". However, I have been reading "C++ Concurrency in Action" and it seems to write a lock-free data structure all you do is stop using mutexes/locks and replace them with atomic code (along with possible memory-ordering barriers).

So my question is- am I missing something here? Is it really that much simpler due to C++11? Is writing a lock-free data structure just a case of replacing the locks with atomic operations?

Answer (score 6):

Ooooo but that ***is*** really complex.

If you don't see the difference between a mutex and an atomic access, there is something wrong with the way you look at parallel processing, and there will soon be something wrong with the code you write.

Most likely it will run slower than the equivalent blocking version, and if you (or rather your coworkers) are really unlucky, it will spout the occasional inconsistent data and crash randomly.

Even more likely, it will propagate real-time constraints to large parts of your application, forcing your coworkers to waste a sizeable amount of their time coping with arbitrary requirements they and their software would have quite happily lived without, and resort to various <s>superstitions</s> good practices to obfuscate their code into submission.

Oh well, as long as the template guys and the wait-free guys had their little fun...

---

Parallel processing, be it blocking or supposedly wait-free, is inherently resource consuming,complex and costly to implement. Designing a software architecture that takes a real advantage from non-trivial parallel processing is a job for specialists.

A good software design should on the contrary limit the parallelism to the bare minimum, leaving most of the programmers free to implement linear, sequential code.

As for C++, I find this whole philosophy of wrapping indifferently a string, a thread and a coffee machine in the same syntactic goo a disastrous design choice.

C++ is allowing you to create a multiprocessor synchronization object out of about anything, like you would allocate a mere string, which is akin to presenting an assault rifle next to a squirt gun in the same display case.

No doubt a lot of people are making a living by selling the idea that an assault rifle and a squirt gun are, after all, not so different. But still, they are.

Comment: I thought the fact you can combine memory ordering with the atomics to produce the equivalent effect of a mutex?

Comment: Not "equivalent". The similarity is that the data won't get overwritten, but a mutex is still a blocking synchronization object, while atomics simply prevent interprocessor read/write operations from interrupting each other.

Comment: No working non-blocking data structure will "propagate real-time constraints" anywhere - what would that even mean? Heck, considering that most code won't run on a RT OS, the whole idea that you could have such a constraint in the first place is flawed. In practice non-blocking is an useful property of an implementation and encapsulated in the actual code for it (with possibly some limitations compared to the blocking version - some operations just can't be made non-blocking).

Comment: No working code will ever cause problems. That's the general acception of "working". Wrong use of the new trendy toys could, however. Real-time constraints would mean, for instance, that people would be forced to coax their code into a framework where each bit of code must feed from "Block free" queues, thus being forced to implement more or less complicated state machines for the promise of performance gains that might never materialize.

Comment: Any examples of what you're talking about? Because when I look at popular nonblocking data structures, the non-blocking part is solely in the implementation with the interface staying the same (you still call `add` to add something to the hashmap, nothing more). [Popular example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/high-scale-lib/). And I've still no idea where "real-time" gets into in your explanation - there are no hard or soft rt constraints involved here whatsoever (obviously because that would be rather problematic under windows or standard *nix kernel)

Comment: @Voo based on my own experience as an embedded software designer (until the early 2000's, so I'm not up to date), the kind of frameworks that are used internally by software companies are not all published on GitHub. Unless a wave of heavenly wisdom has washed over software engineers around the world since I last got paid to coax various bits of hardware into life, I expect a lot of software imbeciles will continue doing a lot of damage designing tools based on techniques they have no clue about. Only more so with the deceptive ease of use provided by C++11 interfaces.

Comment: So your experience is with some ancient, really strange frameworks in the embedded area (generally a paragon of software engineering), but when most people talk about "lock-free data structures" they are, well, talking about *data structures*. And those have clearly defined interfaces that separate the implementation from the caller. Still should leave the implementation to experts, but using them is a different thing.

Comment: @Voo My point precisely. C++11 syntactic sugar does not only give access to data structures, but also to bare component parts like TAS variables or memory barrier setup. The OP's question is rather a good illustration of that problem, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to consider:

1. Only a single operations is atomic when using C++11 atomic.  But often when you want to use mutexes to protect a larger region of code.
2. If you use std::atomic with a type that the compiler cannot convert to an atomic operation in machine code, then the compiler will have to insert a mutex for that operation.

Overall you probably want to stick with using mutexes and only use lock-free code for performance critical sections, or if you were implementing your own structures to use for synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something.  While lock free data structures do use the primitives you mention, simply invoking their existance will not provide you with a lock free queue.

Comment: Would you be able to illustrate why this isn't the case with an example? I ask because the book Concurrency in Action, chapter 7 seems to suggest atomics are enough.

Comment: @meza Atomics *are* enough if you use the right algorithm and are really careful (look up the code for a nonblocking hashmap once in a while, the one by Cliff Click for Java being the best known one). Just makes the algorithm a whole lot more complicated than the trivial blocking version.

Answer (score 0):

Lock-free codes are not simpler due to C++, without C++, operating systems often provides similar stuff for memory ordering and fencing in C/Assembly.

C++ provides a better & easier to use interface (and of course more standardized so you can use in multiple OS, multiple machine structures with the same interface), but programming lock-free codes in C++ won't be  simpler than without C++ if you target only one specific type of OS/machine structure.